# Can't add space before and after the list numbering

Tags: python, list, split, removing-whitespace, trailing-whitespace

I am writing a program in which there are sometimes lists that create issues during voice synthesis, for example the output from voice synthesis is displayed as follows:
**"Suggestions for restaurants:1. Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles..."**. The voice synthesis interprets the numbers as part of the word, resulting in awkward pronunciation. To resolve this, whitespaces should be inserted between the numbers and the words. Additionally, the output should not be too lengthy; it would be better to limit the list to the first three suggestions.

I have tried this code:

```
import re

def post_processing(text):
  """
  Post-processes a text string to address formatting issues for voice synthesis.

  Args:
    text: The input text string.

  Returns:
    The processed text string.
  """
  # Process lists with improved handling
  parts = text.split(":")
  if len(parts) > 1:
    # Split based on newlines, limiting to 3 items
    items = parts[1].strip().split("\n")[:3]
    # Remove trailing spaces, handle punctuation, and add spaces correctly
    items = [
        f"{item.strip()[:-1].rstrip('.')}{' ' if item.strip()[-1].isdigit() or item.strip()[-1] == '.' else ''}{item.strip()[-1:]}"
        for item in items
    ]
    text = ": ".join(items)
  else:
    text = text.strip()  # Remove leading/trailing whitespace

  # Remove URLs completely
  text = re.sub(r"https?://\S+", "", text)

  return text
```

So when I input the following as input:
text = "Suggestions for restaurants: 1 . Pizza2.  Burger3.  Sushi4. Noodles...."
text = post_processing(text)

Following output should be there:
print(text)  # Output: 1. Pizza 2. Burger 3. Sushi

but what I get is as follows:
1 . Pizza2.  Burger3.  Sushi4. Noodles .

Comment: Why don't you match 3 capture groups with a single regex? `:(\d+\..*?)(\d+\..*?)(\d+\..*?)(?=\d+\.|$)` See https://regex101.com/r/oEQfH4/1

Comment: I tried using regex but it still gives me gthe same output. like for example for any input: 1 . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles . I get the output 1 . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles .  Same without any proper numbering within the list.

Comment: Yes, but then you can slightly update the regex to this https://regex101.com/r/tIhbRX/1

Comment: Should i replace your suggested code with this line of code. If I am not wrong: parts = text.split(":")
  if len(parts) > 1:
    # Split based on newlines, limiting to 3 items
    items = parts[1].strip().split("\n")[:3]
    # Remove trailing spaces, handle punctuation, and add spaces correctly
    items = [
        f"{item.strip()[:-1].rstrip('.')}{' ' if item.strip()[-1].isdigit() or item.strip()[-1] == '.' else ''}{item.strip()[-1:]}"
        for item in items
    ]
    text = ": ".join(items)

Comment: You could get the matches like this: https://ideone.com/jmFfRe Or do some after processing like trim for each separate group like this https://ideone.com/q4j9k2

Comment: `" ".join(f"{i}. {p.strip(' .')}" for i, p in enumerate(re.split(r"\d", text)[1:], start=1))`

Comment: but I need a proper string since the output is for a chatbot. A string like this "Suggestions for Restaurants: 1.Pizza  2.Burger  3.Noddles....."

Comment: Then you can join back the separate parts to a string right?

Comment: Yeah that i can do.

Comment: I am still getting error. can you tweak my code block with your regex thing perhaps, it would help me better understand the code,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure there's a space both before and after the list numbering, you can adjust the formatting in the list comprehension.
Try this

```py
import re

def post_processing(text):
    """
    Post-processes a text string to address formatting issues for voice synthesis.

    Args:
      text: The input text string.

    Returns:
      The processed text string.
    """
    # Process lists with improved handling
    parts = re.split(r'[:,]\s*', text, 1)  # Split based on colon and optional space
    if len(parts) > 1:
        # Extract list items with numbers
        items_with_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s*\S+', parts[1])
        # Limit to the first three items
        items = items_with_numbers[:3]
        # Replace consecutive periods with a single period within each word
        items = [re.sub(r'\.+', '.', item) for item in items]
        # Add space before and after list numbering
        items = [f"{item[:-1]}. {item[-1]}" for item in items]
        text = " ".join(items)
    else:
        text = text.strip()  # Remove leading/trailing whitespace

    # Remove URLs completely
    text = re.sub(r"https?://\S+", "", text)

    return text

text = "Suggestions for restaurants: 1. Piz. . 2. Burg. . 3. Sus. . 4. Nood. les...."
text = post_processing(text)
print(text)
```

Comment: It is giving me this output: "1 . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles " which is also wrong since I want is like this: 1.Pizza   2.Burger 3.Sushi". Also, I want to limit my output to first three recommendations even if there are more than 3 options available.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can split on numbers and strip out the leading characters you don't want. Then re-introduce your numbering via `enumerate()`

```py
import re

def post_processing(text):
    """
    Post-processes a text string to address formatting issues for voice synthesis.

    Args:
      text: The input text string.

    Returns:
      The processed text string.
    """

    return "Suggestions for restaurants: " + " ".join(
        f"{i}. {p.strip(' .')}"
        for i, p
        in enumerate(re.split(r"\d", text)[1:-1], start=1)
    )

text = "Suggestions for restaurants: 1 . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles...."
print(text)
print(post_processing(text))
```

Giving you:

```
Suggestions for restaurants: 1 . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles....
Suggestions for restaurants: 1. Pizza 2. Burger 3. Sushi
```

If your ultimate goal is to take your input text and just give the numbers in it proper spacing then maybe I might use:

```
text = "Suggestions for restaurants: 1 . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles...."
text = re.sub(r"\s*(\d)\s*\.?\s*", r" \1. ", text).split(" 4.")[0]
print(text)
```

With the new test:

```py
import re

def post_processing(text):
  text = re.sub(r"\s*(\d)\s*\.?\s*", r" \1. ", text).split(" 4.")[0].strip()    
  if text.endswith("."):
      text = text[:-3]
  return text

print(post_processing("Suggestions for restaurants: 1 . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles...."))
print(post_processing("Recommendation of Stadiums: 1.OldTrafford 2Manchester Birmingham3"))
```

```
Suggestions for restaurants: 1. Pizza 2. Burger 3. Sushi
Recommendation of Stadiums: 1. OldTrafford 2. Manchester Birmingham
```

Comment: yeah this works thanks! only thing is that out of all these options, I need only first three. is there a way in this code that if I tweak, I get the fitst three options only? and also the answer comes with like "Suggestions for restaurants: 1. Pizza  2. Burger 3.Sushi" like this?

Comment: Sure, though if you want to keep the text basically as is and just ensure that there are proper spaces around the numbers then I might approach this with an `re.replace()` rather than what I did here

Comment: You mean for this  return "Suggestions for restaurants: " + " ".join(
        f"{i}. {p.strip(' .')}"
        for i, p
        in enumerate(re.split(r"\d", text)[1:-1], start=1), you would just use re.replace().

Comment: Hello but for example for examples like this: Recommendation of Stadiums: 1.OldTrafford 2Manchester Birmingham3 ; It gives me output like this: Suggestions for restaurants: 1. OldTrafford 2. Manchester Birmingham. How can I fx this?

Comment: Try the second version with `re.sub()`

Comment: Now this gives me the following output: Recommendation of Stadiums: 1. OldTrafford 2. Manchester Birmingham 3.

Comment: Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: if you look after Birmingham it gives the number 3 like Birmingham 3. While what should be done would have been 3. Birmingham

Comment: Strip out that last part

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pattern with 3 capture groups, where each part starts with 1 or more digits followed by a dot.

```
\b(\d+\s*\..*?)(\d+\s*\..*?)(\d+\s*\..*?)(?=\d+\.|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+\s*\..*?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits followed by optional whitespace chars and a dot. Then match the least amount of characters until the next occurrence of the same pattern
- `(\d+\s*\..*?)` Same for **group 2**
- `(\d+\s*\..*?)` Same for **group 3**
- `(?=\d+\.|$)` But as there might not be a 4th occurrence, we can assert the digits and dot to the right, or assert the end of the string

See the [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/tIhbRX/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/am2kvO).

The you can after process the group values.

```
import re


def post_processing(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r"\b(\d+\s*\..*?)(\d+\s*\..*?)(\d+\s*\..*?)(?=\d+\.|$)", re.M)
    matches = pattern.finditer(text)

    for _, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        result = [re.sub(r"(\d)\s+\.", r"\1.", s) for s in match.groups()]
        return " ".join(result)


s = "Suggestions for restaurants:1  . Pizza2. Burger3. Sushi4. Noodles..."
print(post_processing(s))
```

Output

```
1. Pizza 2. Burger 3. Sushi
```

Comment: I also want a statement like "Suggestions for restaurants: 1. Pizza 2. Burger 3. Sushi". Also it should be able to detect other sentence patterns as well. For example "Suggestions for Cities: Mutlan1 LosAngeles2 3.NewYork" should be given like this "Suggestions for Cities: 1. Multan 2. LosAngeles 3. NewYork"

Comment: @Sam, yes but are there more formats that you want to match? So now it ends with a digit, but can you state any global rules for the matches? Or give some more examples? Or create a regex101 demo with examples that should and should not match, and then share it here in the comments? Also, can there be multiple words per match?

Comment: No, simply it should when there is an input string that recommends or suggests something, it should simply distinguish between digits and letters and then list the correct number of first three suggestions after the initial prompt of the string for example the suggestions for restaurants are ..... or the most famous three football stadiums are 1. OldTrafford 2.Liepzig 3.Munich etc. Like this

Comment: @Sam So will a pattern like this cover all your examples? https://regex101.com/r/A0rzlS/1

Comment: if you see it is giving correct output for Restaurants but for cities the numbering is not correct. i.e.  Mutlan1 LosAngeles2 3.NewYork. Also, if there is a url attached to it. It should remove the url as well.

Comment: @Sam Can you give some more examples in a regex101 link?

Comment: Here is the link I have given examples here: https://regex101.com/r/A0rzlS/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256962/discussion-between-sam-and-the-fourth-bird).